# Adobe XD installation on windows 10 is interrupted by an error dialog box that says "The operation was canceled due to some restrictions in effect "

Tags: installation, windows-10, adobe

i'm trying to install Adobe XD on my system but i'm halted by an error that comes in form of a dialog box, it says "The operation was cancelled due to some restriction in effect on this system, please contact your system administrator." My windows 10 is up to date and i have the 1607 anniversary update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this error and i resolved it by doing the installation using the Administrator account that windows 10 creates by default when yo install the OS.

Here is a link to a webpage, the one that helped me http://www.ghacks.net/2014/11/12/how-to-enable-the-hidden-windows-10-administrator-account /

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution. It worked for me. For error code 191.

First find Microsoft Store and open it. 
Then find the 3 dots on the upper right hand corner. Click it and then click Updates and downloads. In that window locate apps installer and microsoft store. Update both the apps. Then restart the computer and start installation.

Answer (score 0):

For the error code 505.

https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/troubleshoot-download-install-logs.html#error505

couple week ago, I disabled the Secondary Logon Windows service...so it was my problem..